# Problem based representation theory book

Tags: rt.representation-theory, soft-question, textbook-recommendation

I am trying to find books similar in the spirit of Ram Murty's Problems in Analytic Number theory or Murty Esmonde's Problems in Algebraic number theory in the field of Representation Theory (of groups, algebras, Lie algebras, possibly even goes in the direction of quivers). I want a book which doesn't provide details but directs me in the right direction via lots of exercises. One other book that kind of fits this category maybe Farb and Dennis's Noncommutative Algebra. But it is not purely focused on representation theory although some of the topics are. Any other suggestions?

Comment: So you like it tough, but do you like it [Pavel Etingof, Oleg Golberg, Sebastian Hensel, Tiankai Liu, Alex Schwendner, Dmitry Vaintrob, and Elena Yudovina, *Introduction to representation theory*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/repb.pdf) tough? Also, [Sophie Morel's *Representation theory* notes](http://web.math.princeton.edu/~smorel/rep_theory_notes.pdf) come with a ton of exercises.

Answer (score 4):

Kirillov’s [*Elements of the theory of representations*](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=412321) is written in quite this spirit. From the original [MR](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=407202):

> The book includes a large number of “exercises” (with hints for proving them), most of them being in fact very nontrivial sketches of results in and out of the literature, or playing an essential role in the proofs of the theorems.

Answer (score 4):

The books by Onishchik-Vinberg and by Etingof et al. might fit into this category, too.

Comment: [Etingof et al.'s notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0827).

Comment: Is the Onischik and Vinberg book you have in mind [Lie groups and algebraic groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-74334-4) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1064110)), [Lie groups and Lie algebras I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-57999-8) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1306737)), or another one?

Comment: I imagine it is the first one (Lie groups and algebraic groups)

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, I was too busy at the time to consult the book itself, which is on my shelf.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the book by William Fulton and Joe Harris : Representation Theory (Springer, corrected edition,551 pages). It contains many exercises, with hints, answers, and references (pp. 516-535).